# Matching data from a list with data into a column in python

Tags: python, list, loops, match

I have a big dataframe, named data, with a several columns and particulary a column "date".

I want to create a new column "days_BH" who said me if the date are a bankholidays or not (=1 for yes and =0 for no).

So first I create a list with the french bank holidays :

```
bank_holidays= ["01-01","05-01","05-08","07-14","11-01","11-11","12-25","08-15"]
```

And I want to match it with the date in the column 'data' which are in type : pandas.core.series.Series (I don't really understand that type).

The column data, with the format : %m-%d, looks like this (the 3 first rows):

```
data
07-05
07-06
07-07
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have this dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
data["data"] = ["01-01", "05-01", "05-08", "07-14", "11-01", "11-11", "11-12", "11-13"]
bank_holidays = ["01-01", "05-01", "05-08", "07-14", "11-01", "11-11", "12-25", "08-15"]
```

Then you can use `.isin()`:

```
data["days_BH"] = data["data"].isin(bank_holidays).astype(int)
```

Printed new dataframe will look like this:

```
    data  days_BH
0  01-01        1
1  05-01        1
2  05-08        1
3  07-14        1
4  11-01        1
5  11-11        1
6  11-12        0
7  11-13        0
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `bank_holidays` list and data field in dataframe `df['data']` are of same type then this should do :

```
 bank_holidays= ["01-01","05-01","05-08","07-14","11-01","11-11","12-25","08-15"]
 df['days_BH'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: x == bank_holidays).map({True: 1, False: 0})
```